# Django customize model.Manager so it accepts arguments

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to be able to pass args or kwargs through `objects` if possible, and without needless complications. It would look something like `Model.objects('something').all()` or `Model.objects('something').order_by('field')`. I tried to customize `__init__` for AManager, but couldn't get it to work, so it might be as simple as writing the appropriate `__init__` function.

What I have done is add a method to a custom Manager, which looks something like this:

```
class AManager(models.Manager):
    def example(self, arg):
        self.example = arg
        return self

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

    objects = AManager()
```

In this example, `A.objects.example('name').all()` would return the usual `A.objects.all()`, unless of course, `example('name')` affects the QuerySet somehow. What I want to do is avoid something like `A.objects.custom_filter('name').another_filter('name')` where I have to include a duplicate arg for each chained filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `__call__` method to your manager which accepts this argument and returns a different query set then the default manager (or another manager based on the argument).

You're better off writing custom query set methods and returning them.  Querysets are designed to be chained, so you shouldn't have to continue to pass the same argument.

If you add your specific use case, I can show you how to construct it using a custom Manager and/or QuerySet classes.

Comment: Some of my queries call on model properties which are expensive to both fetch and calculate. They occur when custom QuerySet methods are called. I now save the calculated values (as a DataList instance). I want to call for the saved values if they exist or a QuerySet, and passing some initial values makes it easier. I can then chain the same methods against both QuerySet and DataList, so the queries are legible and read the same. But under the hood, the operation switches into methods against a Python class when the Django query is too expensive. So how do I customize the `__call__` method?

Comment: Without more concrete code samples, it's hard for me to give you pointers on how to build custom QuerySets that retain state through chaining.  Check out Django-Model-Utils which has a PassthroughManager that can solve the chaining with custom QuerySet methods: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager

Comment: I actually use `PassThroughManager` frequently :)

Comment: Then I'd suggest extending `PassThroughManager` to return different QuerySet class depending on the parameter passed in the `__call__` method.  `def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)` just lets you call a class like a function, so have that function configure the manager to return different a QuerySet class based on the parameter.

Comment: thanks. I think I have figured an approach which can manage this task, and perhaps broader ones. I made another stackoverflow question to check if I was on the correct path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715210/python-tracking-the-use-of-parent-class-methods